# how does below constructor work in dart, I have extracted widget and flutter has given the below constructor for my widget

Tags: flutter, dart

```
ExtractedWidgetForLst({
Key key,
@required List<Expense> expensesData,
}) : _expensesData = expensesData, super(key: key);
```

If we need any argument to be passed to the class, we use parameterized constructor and in that we use super() to call parent constructor inside the body if needed. and if we don't need calling super then just we use this keyword in the parameter itself, e.g:

```
class MyClass{
  String name;
  String surname;
  MyClass({this.name,this.surname});
}
```

but what does operator ' : ' and super means over this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is for the parameter and `super(key: key);` calls the Constructor from the inherited Widget class

Comment: why do we have assignment from left to right , _expensesData = expensesData , usually left one has value of right hand side variable, here widget need expensesData and not _expensesData

Comment: @MrudulAddipalli _expensesData is a private variable that will hold the data provided inside the constructor's parameter.

Comment: okay I understood its a private data but what is the need of writing :  _expensesData = expensesData , as private data is already present with inherited widget, right?

Comment: it'll hold the list items for you.